# Trying to get this code to pull using MAMP and sequelpro using c#

Tags: c#, mamp, sequelpro

I am trying to get this code to pull from a sequel pro database using c# and MAMP and I keep getting the following error after I enter the city name that is for sure in the database.
I don't understand why it's saying that the connection needs to be valid and open as I have an open script in the code.

Input City
Orlando

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Connection must  
be valid and open.
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Throw(Exception ex)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.Throw(Exception ex)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.CheckState()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior 
behavior)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
at ConsoleApp1.SQLWorker.GetData(String city) in 
C:\Users\Colton10\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\SampleAPIData 
2\project\Program.cs:line 35
   at ConsoleApp1.Program.Main(String[] args) in 
C:\Users\Colton10\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\SampleAPIData 
2\project\Program.cs:line 61


    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
    namespace ConsoleApp1
    {
    class Data
    {

        public readonly decimal temp;
        public readonly decimal pressure;
        public readonly int humidity;
        public readonly bool IsValid;
        public Data(decimal t, decimal p, int h, bool v)
        {
            temp = t;
            pressure = p;
            humidity = h;
            IsValid = v;
        }
    }
    class SQLWorker
    {
        public static Data GetData(string city)
        {

            MySqlConnection connstring = new MySqlConnection("Server= 
  localhost; port = 8889; user = root; password = root; database = 
  sampleAPIData; SslMode = none "); 
            MySqlCommand command = connstring.CreateCommand();


            var query = connstring.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT temp, pressure, 
  humidity FROM weather WHERE city='{0}' ORDER BY createdDate desc limit 
1", 
  city);
            MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            connstring.Open();
            try
            {

                reader.Read();
                return new Data(reader.GetDecimal(0), 
reader.GetDecimal(1), 
  reader.GetInt32(2), true);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            while(reader.Read());
            return new Data(reader.GetDecimal(0), reader.GetDecimal(1), 
  reader.GetInt16(2), true);
        }

      }
    class Program
      {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input City");
            string city = Console.ReadLine();

            Data data = SQLWorker.GetData(city);
            if (data.IsValid)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}\n Temperature:{1} Pressure:{2} 
  Humidity:{3}\n", city, data.temp, data.pressure, data.humidity);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No Data Available for the selected 
 city\n");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static Data GetData(string city)
        {
            return SQLWorker.GetData(city);
        }
    }
    }
```